# AJAX (Get, Express, Node JS) to retrieve JSON & HTML data

Tags: html, json, ajax, express, get

I'm working on a web development project where I can retrieve JSON & HTML data from JS file by using AJAX, Get, Express and Node JS.

When the user clicks on one of the lists, I want the JSON & HTML data to show up in my HTML file. I created all the templates, but for unknown reason it's not working properly..

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <title>J MEDICAL | SURREY</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id = "title" href="#">J MEDICAL</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">MEDICATION</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              ABOUT
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">RESOURCES</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class = "container">
    <div id = "question"><h3>INFORMATION</h3></div>
    <div id = "faq">
      <ul id = "questions">
        <li><a href="" id="opening-hour">CLINIC OPENING</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="vaccine-types">COVID-19 VACCINES WE CARRY</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="location">OTHER MEDICAL CENTRES</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="not-permitted">TYPES OF RESTRICTION OF ACQUIRING VACCINE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <script src="main-ajax.js"></script>
  <!--Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JSON & HTML data in JavaScript file

```
const openingInfo = {
    "Monday": "9-5", 
    "Tuesday": "9-5", 
    "Wednesday": "9-5", 
    "Thursday": "9-5", 
    "Friday": "11-5", 
    "Saturday": "CLOSED", 
    "Sunday": "CLOSED"
}

const openingInfo = [
    {
        "day": "Monday",
        "hours": "9-5"
    },
    {
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "hours": "9-5"
    },
    {
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "hours": "9-5"
    },
    {
        "day": "Thursday",
        "hours": "9-5"
    },
    {
        "day": "Friday",
        "hours": "11-4"
    },
    {
        "day": "Saturday",
        "hours": "CLOSED"
    },
    {
        "day": "Sunday",
        "hours": "CLOSED"
    }
]

const vaccineTypes = "<ol><li>Moderna - 18 years older</li><li>Pfizer-BioNTech - 16 years older</li><li>AstraZeneca - 18 years older</li><li>Janssen - 18 years older</li></ol>";
const restrictInfo = "<ul><li>Individuals who have travelled outside of Canada less than two weeks prior.</li><li>Been in contacted with person(s) with COVID-19.</li><li>Have been infected with COVID-19 less than 2 months prior.</li><li>Any signs of symptoms (cough, fever, diahrrea)</li><li>Participated in any gathering of more than 10 people.</li></ul>";
```

JavaScript file to retrieve JSON & HTML file by using AJAX, GET and Node JS.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/js', express.static('files'))
app.use('/css', express.static('files'))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const html = fs.readFileSync('./files/main.html', "utf8");
    res.send(html);
});

app.get("/retrieve-AJAX-info", (req, res) => {
    const formatOfResponse = req.query['format'];
    const dataList = null;
    if(formatOfResponse == 'opening-hour') {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        dataList = lists.opening-hour();
        res.send(dataList);

    } else if(formatOfResponse == 'vaccine-types') {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        dataList = lists.vaccine-types();
        res.send(dataList);

    } else if(formatOfResponse == 'location') {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        dataList = lists.location();
        res.send(dataList);
        
    } else if(formatOfResponse == 'not-permitted') {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        dataList = lists.not-permitted();
        res.send(dataList);
    } else {
        res.send({msg: 'Wrong format!'});
    }
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("<html><head><title>Page not found!</title></head><body><p>Nothing here.</p></body></html>");
  })
  
  // RUN SERVER
  let port = 8000;
  app.listen(port, function () {
      console.log('You are listening to port ' + port + '.');
  })
```

Comment: remove `app.use(function (req, res, next) {` until fixed, its masking the issues, also is a handler for all errors not just 404's. You cant use `const`, then resassign it. Also `lists.opening-hour();`, `lists.vaccine-types()` or `lists.not-permitted()` is not going to work

Comment: So, should I be deleting everything inside app.use(function (req, res, next) {, including the run server part (let port = 8000;)?

Comment: no just comment it out, the run server part is not in it, your also not setting `lists` anywhere

Comment: `lists.not-permitted()` is equivalent to `undefined.undefined-undefined()`, once you add lists, it most likly will be `lists['not-permitted']` which is equivalent to accessing `let lists = {'not-permitted': []}`, is just basic js

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dataList` is defined as a `const` and should be `let` or `var`. Also the `list` variable isn't defined anywhere.

Perhaps inspecting the web browser console will show any other errors in the code.

Comment: Will fix the const to let. Do you mind providing me more explanation of the list variable? Thanks so much.

Comment: The lists variable should be set to the JSON data; otherwise it will always have a value of undefined.